# Is it true that $\langle \psi, \omega\rangle$ is the dimension of $Hom(V,W)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, characters

If $(\psi,V)$ and $(\omega,W)$ are two characters of two representations of a  group $G$, then
$$
\langle \psi, \omega\rangle = \dim \operatorname{Hom}_G(V,W)?
$$
Here $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the standard inner product of characters of representations and $\operatorname{Hom}_G(V,W)$ is the vector space of intertwining operators from $V$ to $W$.

I am guessing this is true from examples I have seen. I think that Schur's lemma in fact says that this is true when $V,W$ are irreducible. But is it true in general? If so, how might one go about proving it? (I am not asking for a complete proof, just the basic idea of it.)

I should maybe add that as a definition the character of a representation is the trace thing.

Comment: Yes, this is the whole point of the inner product.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Ok, I had just never seen this. Feel free to write an answer that I can accept.

Comment: You need $G$ to be finite and you need to be working over a field of characteristic not dividing $|G|$ (or else the inner product of characters is not well-defined).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $\newcommand{\Hom}{\text{Hom}}\Hom(V,W)$ denotes the vector space
homomorphisms from $V$ to $W$ then $\Hom(V,W)$
is a  $G$-module with character $\overline\psi\omega$ and $\Hom_G(V,W)=\Hom(V,W)^G$. Now if $U$ is a $G$-module with character $\chi$ then
$U^G$ has dimension $\frac1{{|G|}}\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)$. Putting all
this together gives the inner product formula.

Comment: Ok, so one needs to kow about induced representations?

Comment: @JohnDoe No. $U^G$ is the $G$-invariant elements of $U$.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense.

Comment: The dimension formula for $U^G$ comes from the observation that 1) the element $\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} g$ is projection onto the fixed points and 2) the trace of a projection is the dimension of its image.

Comment: For future visitors another (longer) explanation of this is found https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278804/product-of-a-character-with-an-irreducible-character-a-non-negative-integer

Answer (score 4):

Just expanding a bit, partially for my own sake.

Note that $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W) \cong V^* \otimes W$ via the isomorphism $v^* \otimes w \mapsto (x \mapsto v^*(x)w)$ which is an iso of representations as well. Using the fac that characters are multiplicative over tensor product, we can check that $\chi_{V^* \otimes W}=\overline{\chi_V} \cdot \chi_W$.

From this, we can see that $\mathrm{dim} (\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)^G)=\mathrm{dim} (V^* \otimes W)^G=\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G}\overline{\chi_V} \cdot \chi_W$

where the last equality comes from the fact that $$\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G}\overline{\chi_V} \cdot \chi_W$$
is a projection onto $(V^* \otimes W)^G$, so it acts by identity on the subspace, and hence the trace agrees with the dimension.

Comment: Oh sorry, replace the $\chi$'s floating around with $\psi, \omega$.